# Django queryset on model with User as foreign key

Tags: python, django, mongodb, django-queryset

My model:

```
class FitDataModel(models.Model):
user = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE)
date = models.DateField()
steps = models.IntegerField(default=0)
distance = models.FloatField(default=0)
calories = models.FloatField(default=0)

def __str__(self):
    return f'{self.user} {self.date} {self.steps}'

class Meta:
    ordering = ['-user']
```

My user model is standart django User model from django.contrib.auth.models.
Queryset:

```
FitDataModel.objects \
     .filter(date__gt=since_data) \
     .values('user__username') \
     .annotate(Sum('steps')) \
     .annotate(Sum('distance')) \
     .annotate(Sum('calories')) \
     .order_by('-steps__sum')
```

And the result is:

```
{
        "user__username": "_id.auth_user.username",
        "steps__sum": 17004,
        "distance__sum": 9411.850049376488,
        "calories__sum": 22582.57051609428
    }
```

This is data for one user, but the problem is I am expecting real username value under the 'user__username' key, not "_id.auth_user.username". I am using mongodb, connected with djongo. What am I doing wrong, how do I extract real username?

Comment: How are you integrating mongodb? Are you using Djongo?

Comment: Yes, I am using djongo.